# How to publish event from a component and receive it from another component in nativescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, nativescript

How can I publish custom event from a component and receive it from another component in nativescript.

something like:

```
ComponentOne.ts
```

```
this.event.publish('someEvent', {name: 'a name'})
```

---

```
ComponentTwo.ts
```

```
this.event.subscribe('someEvent', (data) => {
    const name = data.name;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/) for this case

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {}

    sendMessage(message: any) {
        this.subject.next(message);
    }

    getData() {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

I defined 2 method here. The first method using next() to send message to the next subcriber. So in your component you just need to simply subscribe like this to get the data

```
private subscription$: Subscription;

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subscription$ = this.messageervice
            .getData()
            .subscribe(data => { console.log(data); })
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.
the basic idea is to register a custom event on the root frame of the app and listen on it from the other components

```
ComponentOne.ts
```

```
frameModule.topmost().notify({
    eventName: 'punched',
    object: frameModule.topmost(),
})
```

```
ComponentTwo.ts
```

```
frameModule.topmost().on('punched', () => {
   console.log('event received');
})
```

Comment: Don't do this, Tony's answer is the correct way of doing things. Stop learning Angular for a day or two and go and learn about RxJs. Then come back to Angular and learn about services and dependency injection. If you don't understand the principles of RxJs you should not be doing any Angular just yet. Angular is heavily built upon RxJs.

Comment: This is nativescript specific. it uses RxJs under the hood.

Comment: my answer is based on the nativescript documentation as Tony's answer won't work
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/events#removing-an-event-listener

Comment: Tony's answer is the Angular way of doing things, if you are using Angular with NativeScript then this is how things are done.

Comment: NativeScript does not have dependency injected services but you are using Angular with NativeScript so learn the Angular way. Event soup was what made AngularJs 1.X a nightmare.

Comment: Since you are using {N} Angular flavour, both of your answers work. But the whole point of using Angular is to make use of it's features, so use Angular flavour only if you are familiar with Angular and go with services / rxjs rather {N} Observables which is specifically designed for Core applications.